# Can't connect to MongoDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb, heroku

I'm trying to connect to my database on MongoDB Atlas and keep having this error:

```
throw new Error('invalid schema, expected mongodb');
```

I tried to connect via shell and it worked, so I know the connection is available.

Here is my code:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
let connMongoDB = MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
    db.close();
});

module.exports = function () {
    return connMongoDB;
}
```

In my `.env` I have

```
MONGODB_URI=mongodb+srv://orsUser:password@cluster0-2zrmd.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my `.env` I have
>
> ```
> MONGODB_URI=mongodb+srv://orsUser:password@cluster0-2zrmd.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
> ```

Your `.env` file probably doesn't affect Heroku.

It [generally shouldn't be committed to your repository](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#should-i-commit-my-env-file), and after all this is just a convenient way to populate your running application's [environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable). Heroku embraces [configuration via the environment](https://12factor.net/config) and therefore natively [supports environment variable modification](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) via its command line or web console.

For example, you can run

```
heroku config:set MONGODB_URI='mongodb+srv://orsUser:password@cluster0-2zrmd.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
```

to set the `MONGODB_URI` environment variable. Once you do that your `process.env.MONGODB_URI` should be populated as expected.